# Pull MKAnnotation Subtitle from JSON Array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I am trying to add a subtitle to my MKAnnotation by pulling it from a JSON array. I am able to get the title, and coordinates with my view controller like below, but I can't figure out what to do to get the subtitle to be pulled from the JSON key "cityName". Any help would be great! Thank you!

**MapViewController.m**

```
location.latitude = [dictionary[@"placeLatitude"] doubleValue];
location.longitude = [dictionary[@"placeLongitude"] doubleValue];  

newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:dictionary[@"placeName"]
                                               andCoordinate:location];
```

**MapViewAnnotation.h**

```
@interface MapViewAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
NSString *title;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate; 
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d;
@end
```

**MapViewAnnotation.m**

```
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"
@implementation MapViewAnnotation
@synthesize title, coordinate, subtitle;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d {
title = ttl;
coordinate = c2d;
subtitle = [SUBTITLE PULLED FROM JSON]
return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem here ? Just do exactly what you're doing with the `title` property.

Comment: with this line "- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d" can't I only specify a ttl and a c2d variable?

Comment: no, you can add your `subtitle` property too : `- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d andSubtitle:(NSString *)subTitle`. Be careful to change your method name in `.h` as well

Comment: Thanks Yaman, this may be novice, but am I able to pass other strings as well? lets say I wanted a custom one that could be passed invisibly

Comment: Of course you can. This is a custom initializer, so you can passe every parameters you want to perform additional logic on your annotation.

Comment: OK Thanks, I may open a new question on how to do that properly, unless its extremely simple like tacking it onto the end of that method somehow. Thanks much!!

Comment: How would I add the subtitle to this: newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:dictionary[@"placeName"]
                                                   andCoordinate:location];

Comment: Once you changed your annotation `.h` and `.m`, simply replace your declaration with this : `newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:dictionary[@"placeName"] andCoordinate:location andSubtitle:dictionary[@"someKey"]];`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24362/discussion-between-brandon-and-yaman)

Answer (score 1):

Since there might be situations where you don't initialize every single property your annotation has I'd advise against putting them all into the init method.

Just do this and you won't need to change MapViewAnnotation.m or h

```
location.latitude = [dictionary[@"placeLatitude"] doubleValue];
location.longitude = [dictionary[@"placeLongitude"] doubleValue];  

newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:dictionary[@"placeName"]
                                           andCoordinate:location];
newAnnotation.subtitle = dictionary[@"cityName"];
```